# As I have said or as I said in terms of sequence of tenses

Tags: grammar, sequence-of-tenses

Do sequence of tenses rules apply to sentences starting with "as"? If yes, which tenses should be used?

For example;

As I said (before), you are ...

As I have said (before), you are...

(As far as I know, past tense must be followed by past tense according to rules) Which one is correct according to rules?

Answer (score 1):

There is no rule that "past tense must be followed by past tense".  In fact any sequence of tense "rules" are about good style and not confusing your reader, not about the grammar of English.

> I went shopping this morning but I'm home now.  (fine)

Both the past tense and present perfect forms of your example are correct and idiomatic.  The past tense form would suggest to me:

> As I said before (at a specfic time which we both know), you are....

This suggests that the speaker is referring to a specfic, perhaps recent time, when they told the person the same thing that they are about to say again.  The speaker is about to repeat themselves to the same listener.

> As I have said before (but I don't remember a particular occasion when I told you), you are....

It would seem likely that the speaker is telling the listener something that they have said many times in the past, but perhaps or perhaps not to the listener.  They aren't referring to a specfic time in the past.

As usual, when both past and perfect forms are possible, most speakers prefer the past tense, especially in American English.